# “Unifying” or “unified”?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, past-participles

What is the meaning of a "unifying" view vs. a "unified" view on something (e.g., *a unifying view on the origin of language*)?

What is the meaning of a "unifying" vs. a "unified" something (e.g., *a unified writing system*)?

Google search shows both being used. I wonder if they have enough clarity for formal writing. How does each phrase sounds to native speakers? When should I use which?

Answer (score 1):

The complications with "unifying" and "unified" stem from the ambiguous application of its lemma, "unify". From the dictionary, the word "unify" means to combine somethings, be it either the object (e.g., the war unifies the people in that planet) or the subject of the sentence itself (e.g., the people in that planet struggles to unify in peace).

After noting these points, modifying with -ing or -ed is the same as other words.

Therefore, a "unifying x" means "x" combine somethings; a "unified y" means "y" is a product of a combination. Given these meanings, it requires that "y" is a composition and can be combined when we say "unified y". Other than that, it just matters the intended meaning.

Answer (score 0):

"unified" and "unifying" have almost the same meaning. In some contexts, there is absolutely no difference.

However, when there is a differerence, "unified" is stronger than "unifying".

"Unified" - includes the meaning that the unification has finished. No more work needed.

"Unifying" - means that and end result was not reached. Maybe it is still a work in progress, and unification will happen at some point in the future. But it can also mean that the "unification" is not possible as a goal in itself, but efforts for it are needed perpetually.

For example, some activity can be "unifying". The result of that activity is that something is "unified". But the activity does not need to stop, and other "unified" things will be created consequently.